# Solving System of Second Order Ordinary Differential Equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

*Introduction*

I am using Matlab to simulate some dynamic systems through numerically solving systems of Second Order Ordinary Differential Equations using ODE45.  I found a great tutorial from Mathworks (link for tutorial at end) on how to do this.

In the tutorial the system of equations is explicit in x and y as shown below:

```
x''=-D(y) * x' * sqrt(x'^2 + y'^2)
y''=-D(y) * y' * sqrt(x'^2 + y'^2) + g(y)
```

Both equations above have form y'' = f(x, x', y, y')

---

*Question*

However, I am coming across systems of equations where the variables can not be solved for explicitly as shown in the example.  For example one of the systems has the following set of 3 second order ordinary differential equations:

y double prime equation

```
y'' - .5*L*(x''*sin(x) + x'^2*cos(x) + (k/m)*y - g = 0
```

x double prime equation

```
.33*L^2*x'' - .5*L*y''sin(x) - .33*L^2*C*cos(x) + .5*g*L*sin(x) = 0
```

A single prime is first derivative
A double prime is second derivative
L, g, m, k, and C are given parameters.

How can Matlab be used to numerically solve a set of second order ordinary differential equations where second order can not be explicitly solved for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your second system has the form

```
a11*x'' + a12*y'' = f1(x,y,x',y')
a21*x'' + a22*y'' = f2(x,y,x',y')
```

which you can solve as a linear system

```
[x'', y''] = A\f
```

or in this case explicitly using Cramer's rule

```
x'' = ( a22*f1 - a12*f2 ) / (a11*a22 - a12*a21)
```

`y''` accordingly.

I would strongly recommend leaving the intermediate variables in the code to reduce chances for typing errors and avoid multiple computation of the same expressions.

Code could look like this (untested)

```
function dz = odefunc(t,z)
    x=z(1); dx=z(2); y=z(3); dy=z(4);
    A = [  [-.5*L*sin(x),  1] ;  [.33*L^2,  -0.5*L*sin(x)]  ]
    b = [ [dx^2*cos(x) + (k/m)*y-g]; [-.33*L^2*C*cos(x) + .5*g*L*sin(x)] ]

    d2 = A\b

    dz = [ dx, d2(1), dy, d2(2) ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this response.  Sorry I forgot to mention that I would like to use ODE45.  I used ODE45 to solve a nicer set of differential equations (Lagrange Equations that govern motion of Elastic Spring Pendulum).  Since I cannot use enter in the comments I shall create a new post!

Comment: You solve these equations in the function that computes the derivatives that you pass to ode45. The first derivatives are part of the state, the second ones are the solutions, from which you compose the derivatives vector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your method is correct!
I post the following code below:

```
%Rotating Pendulum Sym Main
clc
clear all;

%Define parameters

global M K L g C;
M = 1;
K = 25.6;
L = 1;
C = 1;
g = 9.8;


% define initial values for theta, thetad, del, deld
e_0 = 1;
ed_0 = 0;
theta_0 = 0;
thetad_0 = .5;
initialValues = [e_0, ed_0, theta_0, thetad_0];

% Set a timespan
t_initial = 0;
t_final = 36;
dt = .01;
N = (t_final - t_initial)/dt;
timeSpan = linspace(t_final, t_initial, N);

% Run ode45 to get z (theta, thetad, del, deld)
[t, z] = ode45(@RotSpngHndl, timeSpan, initialValues);

%initialize variables
e = zeros(N,1);
ed = zeros(N,1);
theta = zeros(N,1);
thetad = zeros(N,1);
T = zeros(N,1);
V = zeros(N,1);
x = zeros(N,1);
y = zeros(N,1);

for i = 1:N
    e(i) = z(i, 1);
    ed(i) = z(i, 2);
    theta(i) = z(i, 3);
    thetad(i) = z(i, 4);
    T(i) = .5*M*(ed(i)^2 + (1/3)*L^2*C*sin(theta(i)) + (1/3)*L^2*thetad(i)^2 - L*ed(i)*thetad(i)*sin(theta(i)));
    V(i) = -M*g*(e(i) + .5*L*cos(theta(i)));
    E(i) = T(i) + V(i);
end

figure(1)
plot(t, T,'r');
hold on;
plot(t, V,'b');
plot(t,E,'y');
title('Energy');
xlabel('time(sec)');
legend('Kinetic Energy', 'Potential Energy', 'Total Energy');
```

Here is function handle file for ode45:

```
function dz = RotSpngHndl(~, z)
% Define Global Parameters
global M K L g C

A = [1, -.5*L*sin(z(3));
    -.5*L*sin(z(3)), (1/3)*L^2];

b = [.5*L*z(4)^2*cos(z(3)) - (K/M)*z(1) + g;
    (1/3)*L^2*C*cos(z(3)) + .5*g*L*sin(z(3))];

X = A\b;

% return column vector [ed; edd; ed; edd]
dz = [z(2);
    X(1);
    z(4);
    X(2)];
```