# Coupled system of 4 differential equations - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, ode, odeint

I have got the coupled system of 4 differential equations in the picture. I have got 4 functions (xG; yG ;gamma; beta) and their derivatives. They are all function of the same independent variable t.

I am trying to solve it with odeint. The problem is that, in order to do so, I think I need to express the system in a way that each second derivative is not dependent on other second derivatives. This involves a quantity of math that will surely take me to an error somewhere (I tried!).

Do you know how I could either:

1. Solve this system of differential equations as it is?
2. or get python to isolate the second derivatives for me?

I am attaching my test code

Thanks

[image: differential equations system]

```
import numpy
import math
from numpy import loadtxt
from pylab import figure,  savefig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Use ODEINT to solve the differential equations defined by the vector field
from scipy.integrate import odeint



def vectorfield(w, t, p):
    """
    Defines the differential equations for the coupled system.

    Arguments:
        w :  vector of the state variables:
                  w = [Xg, Xg1 Yg, Yg1, Gamma, Gamma1, Beta, Beta1]
        t :  time
        p :  vector of the parameters:
                  p = [m, rAG, Ig,lcavo]
    """
#Xg is position ; Xg1 is the first derivative ; Xg2 is the second derivative (the same for the other functions)
        Xg, Xg1,  Yg, Yg1, Gamma, Gamma1, Beta, Beta1 = w
        Xg2=-(Ig*Gamma2*math.cos(Beta))/(rAG*m*(-math.cos(Gamma)*math.sin(Beta)+math.sin(Gamma)*math.cos(Beta)))
        Yg2=-(Ig*Gamma2*math.sin(Beta))/(rAG*m*(-math.cos(Gamma)*math.sin(Beta)+math.sin(Gamma)*math.cos(Beta)))-9.81
        Gamma2=((Beta2*lcavo*math.sin(Beta))+(Beta1**2*lcavo*math.cos(Beta))+(Xg2)-(Gamma1**2*rAG*math.cos(Gamma)))/(rAG*math.sin(Gamma))
        Beta2=((Yg2)+(Gamma2*rAG*math.cos(Gamma))-(Gamma1**2*rAG*math.sin(Gamma))+(Beta1**2*lcavo*math.sin(Beta)))/(lcavo*math.cos(Beta))
        m, rAG, Ig,lcavo, Xg2,  Yg2, Gamma2, Beta2 = p
    
    
    # Create f = (Xg', Xg1' Yg', Yg1', Gamma', Gamma1', Beta', Beta1'):
    f = [Xg1,
         Xg2,
         Yg1, 
         Yg2, 
         Gamma1, 
         Gamma2, 
         Beta1, 
         Beta2]
         
    return f

    


# Parameter values
m=2.722*10**4
rAG=2.622
Ig=3.582*10**5
lcavo=4
# Initial conditions
Xg = 0.0
Xg1 = 0
Yg = 0.0
Yg1 = 0.0
Gamma=-2.52
Gamma1=0
Beta=4.7
Beta1=0

# ODE solver parameters
abserr = 1.0e-8
relerr = 1.0e-6
stoptime = 5.0
numpoints = 250

#create the time values
t = [stoptime * float(i) / (numpoints - 1) for i in range(numpoints)]
Deltat=t[1]
# Pack up the parameters and initial conditions:
p = [m, rAG, Ig,lcavo, Xg2,  Yg2, Gamma2, Beta2]
w0 = [Xg, Xg1,  Yg, Yg1, Gamma, Gamma1, Beta, Beta1]

# Call the ODE solver.
wsol = odeint(vectorfield, w0, t, args=(p,),
              atol=abserr, rtol=relerr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite all your second order derivatives as first order ones and solve 8 ODE together:

[image: formulas]

Then you need initial conditions for all derivatives, but it seems you already have.
FYI, your code does not run (`line 71: NameError: name 'Xg2' is not defined`), please check it.

Also, for further information see [solving the 2nd order ODE numerically](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/second/so_num/so_num.html).

**EDIT #1:**
At the first step, you need to decouple the system of equations. While you could solve it manually, I'd not recommend, so let's use `sympy` module:

```
import sympy as sm
from sympy import symbols

# define symbols. I assume all the variables are real-valued, this helps the solver. If not, I believe the result will be the same, but just calculated slower
Ig, gamma, gamma1, gamma2, r, m, beta, beta1, beta2, xg2, yg2, g, l = symbols('I_g, gamma, gamma1, gamma2, r, m, beta, beta1, beta2, xg2, yg2, g, l', real = True)

# define left hand sides as expressions
# 2nd deriv of gamma
g2 = (beta2 * l * sm.sin(beta) + beta1**2 *l *sm.cos(beta) + xg2 - gamma1**2 *r * sm.cos(gamma))/(r*sm.sin(gamma))
# 2nd deriv of beta
b2 = (yg2 + gamma2 * r * sm.cos(gamma) - gamma1**2 *r * sm.sin(gamma) + beta1**2 *l *sm.sin(beta))/(l*sm.cos(beta))
# 2nd deriv of xg
x2 = -Ig*gamma2*sm.cos(beta)/(r*m*(-sm.sin(beta)*sm.cos(gamma) + sm.sin(gamma)*sm.cos(beta)))
# 2nd deriv of yg
y2 = -Ig*gamma2*sm.sin(beta)/(r*m*(-sm.sin(beta)*sm.cos(gamma) + sm.sin(gamma)*sm.cos(beta))) - g

# now let's solve the system of four equations to decouple second order derivs
# gamma2 - g2 means "gamma2 - g2 = 0" to the solver. The g2 contains gamma2 by definition
# one could define these equations the other way, but I prefer this form
result = sm.solve([gamma2-g2,beta2-b2,xg2-x2,yg2-y2],
                  # this line tells the solver what variables we want to solve to
                  [gamma2,beta2,xg2,yg2] )
# print the result
# note that it is long and ugly, but you can copy-paste it as python code
for res in result:
    print(res, result[res])
```

now we have all the 2nd order derivs decoupled. For example, the expression for `beta2` is
[image: beta2]

so it (and all the other 2nd order derivatives also) has the form

[image: beta2 = f()]

note that there is no dependency on `xg` or `yg`.

Let's introduce the two new variables, `b` and `k`:
[image: substitution by first order]

then the
[image: beta2 = f()]
becomes
[image: beta2 substituted]

and the full system of ODEs to solve is

[image: system of ODEs]

Now all ODEs are dependent on four variables which are not derivatives of anything. Also, since the `xg` and `yg` are degenerated, there are also only 6 equations instead of 8. However, one can rewrite these two equation in the same manner as `gamma` and `beta` to obtain full system of 8 equations, and integrate it together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the first of those equations that you have written is derivative of psi equal to something which is function of the derivative of g. How do I write in python derivative of g?

Comment: You don't need "derivative function" in this approach. You need 8 "simple" functions.

Comment: Thanks, Could you please provide me with a little bit of more detail?
In odeint, I need to define a function of well defined simple functions. How can I define a function that is function of the derivative of another?

Comment: @Francesco, the SciPy cookbook page [Coupled spring-mass system](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CoupledSpringMassSystem.html) gives an example of converting a system of two second order equations into a system of four first order equations.  Take a look and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Warren. That is exactly where I have taken the basis of my code. Unfortunately that example is based on a system where you can easily obtain the second derivatives as functions of either constants or functions of time or their first derivatives. While in my case, I cannot easily obtain a second derivative as function of constants , functions or first derivatives: I always have a second derivative on both sides of the equations. How to proceed in such a case?

Comment: @Suthiro. What can I say? Thanks. Your answer has been incredibly useful.

Comment: You have a linear system in the second derivatives. The most simple procedure is to compute the numerical values of its coefficients, put them into a matrix and right-side vector and apply `numpy.linalg.solve` to get the isolated second derivatives for the given state. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825370/solving-system-of-second-order-ordinary-differential-equation. This occurs regularly in mechanically coupled systems like spring-cart-pendulum or the double pendulum, only that the resulting 2x2 systems are usually solved manually. I thought I had this discussed in more places.